# Replace consecutive integers in an array with ranges

Tags: jq

I want to combine consecutive integers in a sorted array and replace them with ranges using `jq`.

### example 1

> input: `[1,2,3,4,6,98,99,101]`
> desired output: `"1-4,6,98-99,101"`

### example 2

> input: `[1,3,5]`
> desired output: `"1,3,5"`

### example 3

> input: `[1,2,3,4,5]`
> desired output:  `"1-5"`

I have found a solution using `foreach`, but it does not seem very elegant and compact to me.

Is there a simpler solution for this task?

```
[foreach (.[], 99999) as $current
  ({};
   if length == 0 then
     {first: $current}
   elif (has("last") | not) and .first + 1 != $current then
     {first: $current, extract: "\(.first)"}
   elif has("last") and .last + 1 != $current then
     {first: $current, extract: "\(.first)-\(.last)"}
   else
     {first, last: $current}
   end;
   .extract // empty
  )]
| join(",")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
reduce .[1:][] as $n ([.[:1]];
  if $n == .[-1][-1] + 1 then .[-1][1] = $n else . + [[$n]] end
) | map(join("-")) | join(",")
```

When fed with

```json
[1,2,3,4,6,98,99,101]
[1,3,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
[4]
[]
```

it outputs

```json
"1-4,6,98-99,101"
"1,3,5"
"1-5"
"4"
""
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M68QybQtHw)

Comment: very compact solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it in two steps.

---

First, group into ranges.

```
reduce .[] as $_ (
   [];
   if $_ - 1 == .[-1][1] then
      .[-1][1] = $_
   else
      . + [ [ $_, $_ ] ]
   end
)
```

This step produces `[[1,1],[2,4],[6,6],[98,99],[101,101]]`.

---

Then, build the string.

```
map(
   if .[0] == .[1] then
      "\( .[0] )"
   else
      "\( .[0] )-\( .[1] )"
   end
) |
join(",")
```

---

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xou87tXVQS) on jqplay

It's not much shorter, but I think it's a lot simpler and cleaner.

Also, separating the concerns doesn't just have beneficial consequences for simplicity and clarity. You gain the option of hiding the code in two small functions. And you can customize the output more easily, say to produce `98,99` instead of `98-99` for `[98,99]`. You could even decide to reuse the code where you don't need to produce a string at all.

But best of all, this solution eliminates the magic `99999`!

Comment: Note that `$_ == .[-1][1] + 1` fails if the input starts with `1`, which is why I used `$_ - 1 == .[-1][1]`. If the subtraction is off-putting, one could also use `.[-1] and $_ == .[-1][1] + 1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your alternative solution. Good that the magic number is no longer needed for the logic.